# CONCAT Function without OFFICE 365

Tags: excel, vba

I have my data like so, in A1:A3 in excel.

`stack','   over','   flow','`

Is there anyway to combine this into one cell?

I've tried copy and paste to word and notepad ++ but they give me these with space gaps between them. My idea is to use these in a SQL query.

Other questions on here regard VBA for multiple rows. 
Concatenante does not work as in reality I use a larger range then A1:A3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have CONCAT() function:

```
=CONCAT(A1:A3)
```

IF not:

```
= A1 & A2 & A3
```

---

If you do not have CONCAT, put this UDF in a module and use the formula as described above:

```
 Function CONCAT(rng As Range)
 Dim rngArr As Variant
 Dim i As Long, j as long
 rngArr = rng.Value
 For i = LBound(rngArr, 1) To UBound(rngArr, 1)
    For j = LBound(rngArr, 2) To UBound(rngArr, 2)
        CONCAT = CONCAT & rngArr(i, j)
    Next j
 Next i
 End Function
```

Comment: A1 & A2 & A3 work. Concatenate doesn't. Possibly because it is a large range, i just used A1:A3 in question as a sample.

Comment: Not CONCATENATE(), CONCAT() it is different and only available with a subscription to OFFICE 365. @Jonnyboi

Comment: :( I dont got. Sigh i guess this slow way will have to do